# Number of transformations of rank $m$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{T}_n$ be the set of all transformations on $\mathbb{N}_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. For all $\phi \in \mathcal{T}_n$ let $\text{rank}(\phi) := |\phi(\mathbb{N}_n)|$. What is the cardinality of the set $\{\phi \in \mathcal{T}_n : \text{rank}(\phi) = m\}$?

Clearly the first factor must be $n \choose m$, but I am having trouble proceeding from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the answer is the factor you mentionned times the number of surjections from a set of cardinal $n$ to a set of cardinal $m$. The formula for this last number is hard to guess but is a common exercise of combinatorics. You will find by it googling "number of surjections".

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get to the rest of the information I was seeking. Thank you.